# How do I find the correct SOAP URL for my instance of Confluence?

Tags: soap, confluence

I am using `atlassian-cli-3.8.0` to try to connect to a `Confluence 4.0` wiki hosted on my own server.

After configuring the server, username, and password inside the `atlassian.sh` file, I use the command

```
atlassian.sh confluence --action getServerInfo
```

I get the following error (domain and username removed).

> Unable to log in to server: https://mydomain/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v1 with user: <myusername>
>        Cause: (404)Not Found

I then tried the URL above directly in my browser, and got a `404`, as expected.

I have already enabled the remote API using the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Enabling+the+Remote+API), so my best guess is that the SOAP URL is incorrect.

**Is there a way to discover the correct SOAP URL using the wiki's interface, or the command line tool?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this [post](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/browse/CSOAP-55) and trying various fragments of our URL, I realized I just needed to use `http://mydomain/wiki` as the base URL.

More generally, it appears that the first word (between the first and second `/` after the URL) after the domain needs to appended to the domain given to the `--server` option, although this does not appear to be documented anywhere.